# Tutorial for Using Subversion C API in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, ios5

I am looking for a good tutorial to use Subversion(SVN)'s C API in an iPhone/iPad app. I tried finding it on google. If someone can point me to the right article that will be great. Or just getting some pointers would be much appreciated as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some official documentation, pretty explained and straightforward: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch08s02.html

Hope this helps.